# Get desktop path of local machine using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, desktop

I need to read a text file in php. But file will vary based on users that which system they are using.

For example 
user1 access: i want to read a text file from their desktop location like

```
url : "C://Users/user1/desktop/data.txt",
```

user2 access: i want to read a text file from their desktop location like

```
url : "C://Users/user2/desktop/data.txt",
```

so i want to get the current machine desktop path as `C://Users/{username}/desktop`
by using Javascript/PHP?

Comment: Check node's path module. It gives relative path

Comment: JavaScript can not read random files for security reasons and PHP is not going to be able to run on the server and read a random file on a erson's machine.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in PHP as it runs on server side. For JS refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/372333/4350275

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language therefore it cannot read stuff on another computer. I have actually attempted this before in JavaScript and figured that it is not possible to read a file in any way unless the file is uploaded to the website server.

Sorry but what you are trying to do is not possible probably for security reasons and the fact that websites are meant to run in your browser and not on your computer.